# How do I use permessage-deflate in java.net.http.WebSoscket?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a `java.net.http.WebSocket` client with compression enabled, more specifically using the [permessage-deflate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7692#page-12) extension but there doesn't seem to be an option using `WebSocket.Builder`. I tried setting the `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate` header manually:

```java
WebSocket ws = HttpClient
        .newBuilder()
        .build()
        .newWebSocketBuilder()
        .header("Sec-WebSocket-Extensions", "permessage-deflate")
        .subprotocols(protocol)
        .buildAsync(uri, new WebSocket.Listener() { /** ... */ } )
        .join();
```

But that's not allowed as per the Javadoc of [java.net.http.WebSocket.Builder#header](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/WebSocket.Builder.html#header(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)):

> Headers defined in the WebSocket Protocol  are illegal.

Trying to set the `Sec-WebSocket-Extensions` header results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal header: Sec-WebSocket-Extensions
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.illegal(OpeningHandshake.java:356)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.<init>(OpeningHandshake.java:125)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.WebSocketImpl.newInstanceAsync(WebSocketImpl.java:139)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.BuilderImpl.buildAsync(BuilderImpl.java:120)
```

I am using Java 19. Are there any options to enable compression using the built-in `WebSocket` client?